# How do I install Susy in my Rails App?

Tags: css, sass, susy-compass, susy, susy-sass

So far in my Gemfile i included

`# Gemfile
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'susy'`

`# config/application.rb
require 'susy'`

I ran "bundle install" with no errors. Now i'm trying to write normal Susy and just set up the app:

`$susy: (
  columns: 12, /* we want our page to have 12 columns */
  gutters: 3/4, /* space between columns with be 3/4 of a column */
  math: fluid,
  output: float,
  gutter-position: inside,
);`

Now when i try and call Susy methods to set up columns, i'm getting errors! I tried a simple column on an element:

`.example{
@include span(3 of 12)
    ;}`

Any ideas? Am i missing something in the install process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to `@import 'susy';` somewhere in your Sass files, before you can call Susy methods.

Comment: Wow - honored to have an answer from you! Rookie mistake. Thanks for your great grid-system and perfect answer!

Comment: Glad you like it. Cheers!